# Docker run in pipeline says `docker: Error response from daemon: authorization denied`

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to setup a bitbucket pipeline and that uses a `docker run` statement. But build fails with the following error message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: authorization denied
```

Here is the pipeline configuration

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          # build the Docker image (this will use the Dockerfile in the root of the repo)
          - docker build -t solc .
          # Test the solidity files in project
          - docker run solc
```

**Question:** I did not perform any operation requiring authorization. Why is the error message talking of authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running docker commands on a shared environment. As of the time of this question, Bitbucket does not allow you to run `docker run` commands in that environment for security purposes. The list of docker commands you can run (as of the time of this question) are:

- docker login
- docker build
- docker tag
- docker pull
- docker push
- docker version

Docker is a client/server application. You are running the client commands and bitbucket has secured their environment on the dockerd daemon.

You can see the current capabilities of their docker integration [from their documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines-879254331.html) which has been extended since this question was first answered. As of the time of this update, it filters privileged containers and mounting host volumes outside of a predefined subdirectory.

Comment: Bitbucket Pipelines has been updated to support more commands, including Docker run, now. The full list of commands can be found here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines-879254331.html

Comment: The accepted answer is stale. It needs to be updated.

Comment: @ShamasisBhattacharya A stale answer implies that the same question still applies to new visitors of the site and that the correct answer has since changed. In this case, the question itself is now stale, but is no less valid given when it was asked. Including relevant quotes and details from a link is encouraged on SO since links change over time and people need to see the answer as it was posted given when it was posted.